# How to use a literal #1 inside \newcommand

Tags: macros

I am trying to define a command that replaces its argument in one place but keeps a literal #1 in another place. If I define it as

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
#1.#1%
}
```

then obviously both #1 will be replaced by the argument. How do I protect the second #1 from replacement with the argument?

Answer (score 5):

Use `##1` as `##` is replaced by `#` in the same way that `#1` is replaced by the first argument.

Comment: Thank you very much, David. It says so plainly on p.203 of TeXbook but I managed to miss it!